# Selenium: Using getLocation and getSize to Interact with Element

Tags: java, css, selenium, xpath

I'm using Java + Selenium and I'm aware it's possible to get the location of an element using `getLocation()` or the size of an element using `getSize()`.

My question is: Is it possible to somehow use this information to interact with an element? For example, if I know the size or location of an element can I perform a `.click()` method (if it is a button) or `.sendKeys()` (if it is a text field) on the element?

And finally, can I use the location or size to get the ID/XPath etc of the element?

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate through all the elements on the page, checking the size/location. When you find one that matches your criteria, you have your ID.

It wouldn't make sense for Selenium to provide this functionality because there may be more than one element with the same size and/or location.

Comment: Nice thought.. Wondering if anyone could come up with any other ideas.. And BTW, it's possible to combine both location and size to find unique elements so I think such implementation makes sense. And further, location is almost always unique. What two elements share same location?

Comment: I agree that in practice you are unlikely to find duplicates, but it's possible in theory so it would be a silly feature for Selenium to provide. What about <a><span></span></a>? Do those elements not have the same size and location?

Comment: Also elements could be absolutely positioned on top of one another. Even if there in different places on the DOM they could be rendered at the same location with the same size.

Comment: What do you mean absolutely positioned one on top of one another?